# Merging some of the polygon boundaries using sf in R

Tags: r, geojson, shapefile, r-sf

I am trying to plot the boundaries from this [geojson](https://gist.github.com/Vonter/a1f0f9d50a587ce059ddcfb086fc0fac#file-police-station-boundary-geojson) file.

I am able to plot all the boundaries using `sf` in `R`. However, I would like to merge some polygons together - e.g., `POL_STN_NM = PS RAJ PARK, PS SULTAN PURI, PS MANGOL PURI` - should be plotted as having one area.

However, using `st_union` is not removing the internal boundaries.

Could someone please help me with this? I am new to spatial mappings.

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ring of that union is an exterior ring, you can extract it and turn it to polygon & sfc to get a polygon without holes:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr)

pls <- st_read("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Vonter/a1f0f9d50a587ce059ddcfb086fc0fac/raw/fcf1b53987b15bb9ee37820e655ae874b8e214fa/Police%2520Station%2520Boundary.geojson")
with_holes <- pls[pls$POL_STN_NM %in% c("PS RAJ PARK", "PS SULTAN PURI", "PS MANGOL PURI"), ] |>
  st_union()
ext_ring <- st_polygon(with_holes[[1]][1]) |> st_sfc(crs = st_crs(pls))

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(with_holes)
plot(ext_ring)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

For some additional context:

> POLYGON   : geometry with a positive area (two-dimensional); sequence of points form a closed, non-self intersecting ring; **the first ring denotes the exterior ring**, zero or more subsequent rings denote holes in this exterior ring
> https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html#simple-feature-geometry-types

> Simple feature geometries are implemented as R native data, using the
> following rules
>
> 1. a single POINT is a numeric vector
> 2. a set of points, e.g. in a LINESTRING or ring of a POLYGON is a matrix, each row containing a point
> 3. **any other set is a list**
>
> https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html#sfg-simple-feature-geometry

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for helping with this.:) The exterior ring was the missing puzzle. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Glad it helped, removing holes is also implemented in few packages, `nngeo::st_remove_holes()` for example, it applies pretty much the same logic but is bit more generic and provides some extra control over hole sizes.  That particular geojson is bit tricky as at first glance it seems to have some slivers, though those areas between polygons do seem to be there on purpose and are mostly related to the rail network, but they do cause some deep cuts / concaves in the resulting union.

Comment: Yes, that is true, those slivers are there exactly because of the rail boundaries. So, in such a case, is it better to use ```nngeo::st_remove_holes()``` or the solution you mentioned above. I am okay with these cuts between the unions - in fact it would be helpful of there is some way of labelling these slivers as well, or extracting their boundary geometry.

Comment: For a single shape it does not really matter, nngeo uses basically the same aproach, though implemented more elegantly as it just replaces the shape instead of converting it to sfc - https://github.com/michaeldorman/nngeo/blob/fcfde8ee0d236494aad120e0b86b5b21d7a2c7b0/R/st_remove_holes.R#L98 . But it sure is more generic, works with sf object and can handle multipolygons. To extract holes as polygons you could use st_difference.